# "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when adding a WCF service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a WCF service to manage trace events, like :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEvents
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<BOEvent> GetEvents(int numResults = 100);


    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void AddEvent(BOEvent);
}
```

I compile it and within VS2010 and added a 'Service Reference', but I am geting the following error:

[image]

My service is running fine, I can see it and its wsdl inside the broswer.

What's going wrong?

Comment: I guess this is caused because of the usage of the optional parameters `int numResults=100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the same problem found here:

[VS 2010 Error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” when adding Service Reference for WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692457/vs-2010-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-adding)

The problem is that there was a service reference with the same name in the same solution. After **removing** the project that contained it i managed to add the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't AddEvent parameter BOEvent have name too rather than just type? Does that even compile?

Comment: Yes, it's a mistyping error, but this is not the problem, i have just found the solution.